# "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when running ota_from_target_files of Android Release Tools

Tags: android, build-tools

I've tried a number of formats when running ota_from_target_files from Android Release Tools and haven't been able to figure out the source of my `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error.

```
parallels@ubuntu:~/Git$ /home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files /home/parallels/Git/tmp/ota-dest.zip /home/parallels/Git/tmp/ota_update.zip

unzipping target target-files...
(using device-specific extensions from target_files)
--- can't determine the cache partition size ---
loaded device-specific extensions from /tmp/targetfiles-hVvBNo/META/releasetools.py
using prebuilt recovery.img from IMAGES...
using prebuilt boot.img from IMAGES...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1801, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1757, in main
    WriteFullOTAPackage(input_zip, output_zip)
  File "/home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 643, in WriteFullOTAPackage
    recovery_img, boot_img)
  File "/home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 1491, in MakeRecoveryPatch
    _, _, patch = d.ComputePatch()
  File "/home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 1151, in ComputePatch
    p = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/parallels/Git/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 87, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if the imgdiff tool is available:
`find out/host/ -name "*imgdiff*"`

Try running `make otatools` to build the imgdiff executable.